# Uniqueness of Android phone meta data

Tags: android

I need to know from the info listed here from a standard android smartphone:

IMEI

IMEI SV

SYSTEM VERSION

BASEBAND VERSION

KERNAL VERSION

BUILD NUMBER

1. How many items here are unique to the device.
2. How much is tamper-proof - Other than IMEI (first item) which i know can be illegally 'unblocked'.
3. What are the odds (percentage) that any two devices could duplicate the data.

By 'Unique' i mean specific to the the actual instance of the device; not the model. Just as we all have finger-prints but yours are  unique to you.

Comment: IMEI is the only unique info. Although it can be changed, many apps use it to identify the device.

Comment: @user962902 you don't need to type all those html tags in question, just select the text and click on the list icon on the tool bar.

Comment: @Mithun - ok so items in the list could potentially be identical in two or more devices ??